# Count distinct values with SELECT query results with error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a weird situation. I need to select all data from table name with distinct values from other table.

Here is database scheme of database that I need to get distinct values:

[image]

When I run both queries without INNER JOIN they run without error but when I use INNER JOIN I got error

This is query that I used:

```
SELECT * FROM `todo`
INNER JOIN 

SELECT `task`.`status`,COUNT(*) as count FROM `task`
ON `todo`.`id`=`task`.`id_list` WHERE `todo`.`user_id` = 43
```

As you can see I need to get total count of status column from other table. Can it be done using one single query or do I need to run two querys to get data...

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: @David-McQ Error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT `task`.`status`,COUNT(*) as count FROM `task`
ON `todo`.`id`=`task`.`id_l' at line 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the join In parenthesis

```
SELECT td.*, t.* 
FROM `todo` td
JOIN
(   SELECT `status`, SUM(status=0) as status_0, SUM(status=1) as status_1 , id_list
    FROM `task`
    GROUP BY id_list 
) t ON td.id= t.id_list
WHERE td.user_id = 43
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. When I run your query it works but problem is that I got only status and Count column as results... I need records from todo database too

Comment: I tried your code but now I got empty result. Query runs fine but there is no results... Do I need to group them?

Comment: It may be you dont have any matching records in the tables for that user. Try a different user

Comment: @JohnRuddell: I think there's a `GROUP BY` clause missing in the inline view query.

Comment: Spencer yes you are correct, my mistake.. Sometimes being on my mobile isnt conducive to answering :/

Comment: I have wired issue with your example. When I run it I got distant values of status but I want distant values when status is equal 0 and when status is equal 1. With your code I got total count of status column but I need to get total count when column status equals 1 and when column status equals 0

Comment: @jureispro well thats a different requirement. I edited with that solution. Let me know if that doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one query.  Even without a subquery:

```
SELECT ta.status, COUNT(*) as count
FROM todo t INNER JOIN 
     task ta
     ON t.id = ta.id_list
WHERE t.user_id = 43  
GROUP BY ta.status;
```

EDIT:

If the above produces what you want, then you probably need:

```
SELECT t.*, ta.status, taa.cnt
FROM todo t INNER JOIN 
     task ta
     ON t.id = ta.id_list INNER JOIN
     (SELECT count(*) as cnt, ta.status
      FROM task ta
      GROUP BY ta.status
     ) taa
     on ta.status = taa.status
WHERE t.user_id = 43  ;
```

You seem to want a summary at the `status` level, which is only in `task`.  But you want the information at the row level for `todo`.

Comment: you code is working but I need data from todo database. With you query I got only column status from task database